# How to display the applet viewer in java?

Tags: java

I have tried a program .. It got executed .. And successfull got run. 
I have used the command 
appletviewer filename.java

When i execute that command in command prompt it got run but applet is not viewed.

```
//Demonstrate the keyEvent handlers
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.applet.*;
/* applet code = SimpleKey width=300 height=300></applet> */
public class SimpleKey extends Applet implements KeyListener
{
    String msg = "";
    int x = 10,y=20;
    public void init()
    {
        addKeyListener(this);
    }
    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent ke)
    {
        showStatus("Key Pressed");
    }
    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent ke)
    {
        showStatus("Key Released");
    }
    public void keyTyped(KeyEvent ke)
    {
        msg+=ke.getKeyChar();
        repaint();
    }
    public void paint(Graphics g)
    {
        g.drawString(msg,x,y);
    }

}
```

Comment: Please post your code. Have you compiled your .java file?

Comment: The appletviewer is only for applets - an outdated technology for running Java programs within a webbrowser. You should not develop new applets. Anyway you always have to compile you Java code before you can run it. Use Javac from JDK to compile it.

Comment: I have posted my code....Yea i have compiled my .java file

Answer (score 1):

To run applet the file should have the `<applet>` tag. Normally a HTML file will be used and the applet tag will be place there.

```
<applet code="ClassName" width= 300 height = 300> </applet>
```

save the file as test.html and use `appletviewer test.html`.

or

If you want to use the java file itself just put the applet code in side comment.

---

**Update:**

In your java file the applet tag is in correct.

Instead of

```
/* <applet code = SimpleKey width=300 height=300></applet> */
```

you have

```
/* applet code = SimpleKey width=300 height=300></applet> */
```

You are missing `<` at the beginning.

Comment: docs: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/windows/appletviewer.html

Comment: Yea i have done the same.. But i am not getting the applet viewer

Comment: @KarthikeyanVaithilingam thank you so much... I have seen the code lot of time. But i didn't find it.. Thank you ...